# Virtual Directory displayed as not under source control

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013

We use a virtual directory for a website in VS 2013. The virtual directory was added after the project was upgraded to VS 2013.

The files in the virtual directory have no source control item, and upon editing them VS will complain that they are write protected. The edited files will not be in the "Included Changes" (or excluded changes). There is no context menu option to add the files to source control but there is a compare option.

In source control explorer the files look alright and under source control. I currently check the files in there. Can I fix this so VS will recognize source control for all files again?

EDIT: The annoying problem is still there. The images below hopefully demonstrate what is wrong. The files under "Mobile" are not under source control and I cannot add them (or new files in the virtual directory) to tfs source control. I must use team explorer where everything works fine.

[image: Solution Explorer]

[image: No Source Control Options to Add to TFS]

Comment: TFS doesn't know anything about the virtual directories in your web server. How could it have any idea about them?

Comment: @John VS 20013 introduces an "Add" -> "New Virtual Directory..." solution explorer option for websites. One will then see a virtual directory inside the website in solution explorer. TFS cannot know about it, but VS does, and VS could display the contents of the virtual directory with source control support.

Comment: But why would there be source control for some random virtual directory? This is yet another reason to stay away from web site "projects".

Comment: Are you suggesting that Visual Studio should add the physical directory corresponding to the virtual directory to your current workspace?

Comment: I required a virtual directory inside a website so it could have its own web.config to overwrite / reset some of the website settings. I would not have used a website project in the first place but that was mandatory for the (aged) project. It is not a random directory, it is a subdirectory of the website and under source control anyway - source control can just not be handled inside the virtual directory in VS solution explorer.

Comment: Interesting. Why was a virtual directory required? You can just put the web.config in a physical directory, in general.

Comment: In that case, I should not have used the virtual directory in the first place, it only gave me trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be by design with virtual directories in VS 2013. If one adds a virtual directory, it will mirror the contents of the original folder, but not display source control options. If one, like I did, adds a virtual directory with the same name as the original folder, then source control becomes unavailable for that folder in solution explorer.

BTW: if one deletes a virtual directory, then the original folder will also be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

As you said this is by design or rather, they just haven't made it there yet.  Virtual folders in websites have been on many people's wishlist for a long time.  They are very useful if you have large set's of fairly static resource files(PDFs, theme images, etc..), that you don't want to include in the project because they make deploying/publishing take longer. I know if you are using build servers that doesn't really matter as much, but that isn't always the case.  Also they're helpful if you want changes to a file to be shared across multiple sites/applications.

Anyways, in case you haven't heard of them, Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2013 Power Tools, are useful for managing TFS via windows Explorer.